# How can I visualize the test samples of k nearest neighbour classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, knn

I want to visualize 4 test samples of k-NN Classifier. I have searched it but I could not find anything. Can you help me with implementing the code?

Here is my code so far,

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=0.3)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.04, random_state=42)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
```

Through a 1×4-axis figure. For each axis, I want to visualize training samples, corresponding testing sample (indicated with ‘+’ marker) as well the nearest k neighbors of that sample (indicated with green border color). The title of each axis should state predicted class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you will basically need to reconstruct the KNN algorithm itself because it doesn't keep track of which "neighbors" were used to make prediction for a given sample.

How you are going to do that depends on what distance metric is being used by the KNN algorithm.

For example, you can define a function to fetch the nearest neighbors based on the `L1` (Manhattan distance) like this:

```
def get_neighbors(xs, sample, k=5):
    neighbors = [(x, np.sum(np.abs(x - sample))) for x in xs]
    neighbors = sorted(neighbors, key=lambda x: x[1])
    return np.array([x for x, _ in neighbors[:k]])
```

Where `xs` is your training set and `sample` is the point for which you want to make the prediction.

Now you can easily visualize it by scattering training points, testing point and the neighbors on the plot.

```
_, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, figsize=(15, 5))
for i in range(4):
    sample = X_test[i]
    neighbors = get_neighbors(X_train, sample, k=5)
    ax[i].scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c="skyblue")
    ax[i].scatter(neighbors[:, 0], neighbors[:, 1], edgecolor="green")
    ax[i].scatter(sample[0], sample[1], marker="+", c="red", s=100)
    ax[i].set(xlim=(-2, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

You can style it as you like by adding appropriate parameters to `scatter` method. Note that I am clipping it here by setting `xlim` and `ylim`, you can change these too but be careful to keep the 1:1 ratio between x and y axis, otherwise the neighbors may look incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much! You answer is really clear. I learned many things